# product of cyclic groups G1 and G2

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G_1= \langle a \rangle$, $G_2= \langle b \rangle$ be two cyclic groups of orders $m$ and $n$ s.t. $(m,n)>1$. Then which one is not true for the product group $G=G_1×G_2$?

> (a) $G$ is cyclic
>
> (b) $G$ is abelian but not cyclic
>
> (c) $O(G)=mn$
>
> (d) none

Comment: What work do you have so far on this problem?

Comment: I cant get around the case (m,n)>1

Comment: $(m,n) > 1$ is simply saying that $m$ and $n$ are not relatively prime. Can you try some examples, say $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, to determine if one of the options is false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a)$ is obviously false, as $(m,n) > 1$ and the Klein Four-Group ($\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$) is a counter example. Note that if the orders we're coprime by Chinese Remainer Theorem this is true.

$b)$ is true as, both $G_1$ and $G_2$ are cyclic, hence both of them are abelian, so $(x_1,y_1)(x_2,y_2) = (x_1x_2,y_1y_2) = (x_2x_1, y_2y_1) = (x_2,y_2)(x_1,y_1)$

$c)$ seems to be true too, as $O(G) = O(G_1 \times G_2) = O(G_1)\cdot O(G_2) = mn$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** If $k=LCM(m,n)$ then what is $a^k$? What is $b^k$?